# How to change the text of DataGridViewTextBox column programmatically?

Tags: c#, gridview, datagridviewtextboxcell

I have a DataGridView of type 'DataGridViewTextBoxColumn' in which following fields are there :

```
SrNo. |    Description   |    HSNCode    |    Qty    | Rate    | Amount
```

I want allow the user to enter the item Description , Qty and Rate

The "SrNo." column is `read only` I want to generate the SrNo. automatically as the user enters to "Description" cell i.e. I want to display the row index in that cell.

And also I want to calculate the  "Amount" (Qty*Rate) in my program as user leaves the "Qty" field.

I tried the following code :

```
private void grdData_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
        {
            grdData.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value = e.RowIndex.ToString();

        }
        else if (e.ColumnIndex == 5)
        {
            grdData.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value = 
            ((Convert.ToDouble(grdData.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3])) *    
            (Convert.ToDouble(grdData.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4]));
        }
    }
}
```

How to do so?

Comment: Did you tried _anything_?

Comment: Yes Sir, I tried to write the code in `CellValueChanged()` event but nothing works @SonerGönül

Comment: Can you please try to use .Value while multiplying the two cells like
 Convert.ToDouble(grdData.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value and similarly for the Cells[4].Value